# Unable to save JSON config file updates in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed a .NET Core app services to Azure.  From time to time I want to go in and update the JSON config file but it doesn't save

It always gets a 409 error

[image: Error]

This has only recently started occurring.  It is quite annoying to have to build and deploy to test a simple config change

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Why are you not using "App Configuration"?

Comment: How about use App Service Editor in preview that lets you edit any of the files you've deployed? Check if this thread give any help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206779/how-can-i-change-a-setting-in-appsettings-json-after-auto-deploy

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying your App Service from Azure Pipelines, and if deployment mode is "Zip deploy", then you will get this error when trying to edit any config files[e.g host.json etc].
To get this resolved, change the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` to 0 and then make your changes to the config JSON file. After all your diagnosis is done, you can revert to 1, but this will reinstate all the originally deployed files, so you will *loose* your changes.
If you are in dev cycle, and need to do this often, then change your pipeline Task to be 'web deploy'.
When deploying to staging/prod, you can use Zip deploy[i.e run from package].

[image]